# child with element of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I read the whole database but can't get the following working.

My aim is to color the rows in a table depending on a child's child element.
I prefer when the innerhtml of the child element will be the name of the class of the row -element.
But it's also OK when i select all `<tr>`-elements which have a `<div>`-element with class "red", and add a class "red" to that.

**Simple solution**

I want to add the class "red" to the `<tr>`-element by inspecting if there is a `<div>`-element with class "red".

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="red">OK</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    this will color along
  </td>
</tr>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzhuH.png')

I am able to add a class to the `<tr>`-element when there's a `<div>`-child in it. So this works:

```
$( "tr:has(div)" ).addClass( "red" );
```

But now I need to do this when and only when the `<div>` has class "red". So I tried:

```
$( "tr:has(div.hasClass( "red" ))" ).addClass( "red" );
```

You're allowed to laugh!! I hoped this would work.

Is there a way this can be done?

---

**Even better but more difficult**

I prefer to use the innerhtml of the `<div>`-element to give the class that name, but that seems to be some bridges too far?!

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="restyle">red</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    this will color along
  </td>
</tr>
```

---

**Even better but impossible?!**

Actually I prefered doing it by css but I found out that is impossible.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Also, next time, care your quotes :)

Comment: I can't remember the details , but yes.  Use CSS subselectors. I think the one you want is TR < TR which is tr within tr. Other subselectors are + - and : please look them up.  I can post an example webpage if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:has()` takes a selector, not Javascript code.

You want `tr:has(div.red)`

Comment: Wow, what a quick answers. Thank you all very much. I need some time to interpret all. I already saw that SLaks had a correct suggestion. Now I need time to read all the answers but for all of you: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer works perfect, I can use the more difficult at one place, but these at other places. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

How about `$('div.red').parents('tr:first').addClass('red')` ?

SLaks' way (using [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) ) is also good, but it would also find tr that contains other tr that contains a red div. The code above affects only the first tr parent of red divs.

For the content of the div use the [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your answer. Now i can use them both, because sometimes I have a table in a table and want to have the tr that contains the other tr. And other times I need your option. And i can transform it at other places. Now I understand everything.

Answer (score 0):

(Concerning the *Even better but more difficult* part:)

Even though I would never rely on an element content for styling its parent, you can use `$.addClass`:

```
$('tr').addClass(function(){
  return $(this).find('.restyle').text()
})
```

Comment: Oops, now I see I may not thank. This one really works great in my situation. My toolbox is filled with 4 perfect tools. The thing is that I can control a cell in a database format from a commercial party. And now I can  control formats that I couldn't control.

Answer (score 0):

select the `div` first, than go up the tree from there using `.closest()`

**simple solution:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.red').closest('tr').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="red">OK</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        this will color along
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**hard solution:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('div.restyle').each(function() {
    var color = $(this).text();
    console.log(color);
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass(color);
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="restyle">red</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        this will color along
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="restyle">blue</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        this will color along
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have implemented this also somewhere. And you made it very clear with the snippets.